# Consolas Font In Vista And Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, fonts, putty

I have downloaded the Consolas font [from Microsoft](http://www.Microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22e69ae4-7e40-4807-8a86-b3d36fab68d3&displaylang=en) and installed it on my Windows Vista box.  Consolas is also present on my Windows 7 box.  When I use PuTTY, being sure to use the same settings on both machines, the Windows 7 box can render Unicode line/box drawing characters in Consolas, but the Windows Vista box cannot.

What is the relevant difference between them?  If Consolas has the characters, why would they only appear on one system, and not on the other?  I am logging into the same remote host each time, and I have been very carefully checking PuTTY's settings to make sure that they're the same on both machines.

How can I make Consolas render Unicode line-drawing characters on Vista?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Microsoft modified Consolas with Windows 7 to include the line drawing characters.  The reason you don't see them on your Vista system is that the version of Consolas you have installed simply doesn't contain those characters.

To get the line/box characters to show up on your Vista system, copy the Consolas font from your Windows 7 system.